# Disabled/Custom params_parser per action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, parsing, nokogiri, parameters

I have a create action that handles XML requests. Rather than using the built in params hash, I use Nokogiri to validate the XML against an XML schema. If this validation passes, the raw XML is stored for later processing.

As far as I understand, the XML is parsed twice: First the Rails creates the params hash, then the Nokogiri parsing happens. I've been looking for ways to disable the params parsing to speed things up but have found nothing.

```
ActionController::Base.param_parsers[Mime::XML] = lambda do |body|
  # something
end
```

I know it's possible to customize the XML params parsing in general using something like the above, but I depend on the default behaviour in other controllers.

Is it possible to bypass the params parsing on a per-action basis? What options do I have?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the problem using Rails Metal. The relevant part looks something like this:

```
class ReportMetal
  def self.call(env) 
    if env["PATH_INFO"] =~ /^\/reports/
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      if request.post?
        report = Report.new(:raw_xml => request.body.string)
        if report.save # this triggers the nokogiri validation on raw_xml
          return [201, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml' }, report.to_xml]
        else
          return [422, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml' }, report.errors.to_xml]
        end
      end
    end
    [404, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, "Not Found."]
  ensure
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
  end
end
```

Thanks!

PS: Naive benchmarking with Apache Bench in development shows 22.62 Requests per second for standard Rails vs. 57.60 Requests per second for the Metal version.